# How can voltage of a battery be calculated?

Tags: voltage

If voltage is calculated using the formula V=IR, how can the voltage be calculated of a battery if it is not connected to anything (i.e. no current)? I am not 100% sure about this, but neither do I think there is a resistance. Thus, how can V be calculated when both I (current) and R (resistance) are unknown?

Comment: Your formula is only valid for resistive elements with a voltage across it. Everything isn’t based around this. s=v*t, yet I am stationary. How can that be?

Comment: battery is not a resistor

Comment: V can be measured directly, or calculated using chemistry. You don't need to know I or R to measure battery V.

Answer (score 2):

The open-circuit voltage of a battery is based on the electrochemical potentials of the constituent materials. The theoretical voltage is determined by the [Nernst Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation). You can look up the half-cell potentials. There is a temperature dependence which the Nernst Equation will predict.

[Here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/materials-science-and-engineering/3-014-materials-laboratory-fall-2006/labs/w3_b1.pdf) is a simple undergrad lab where the students are asked to work this out for an ordinary lead-acid battery.

In practice electrical engineers are usually going to refer to the battery or cell datasheet for the range of voltages and the (usually more important) characteristics under various discharge conditions (and charge conditions, where applicable).

Answer (score 2):

If the battery is not connected to anything, no current is flowing but voltage still exists across its positive and negative terminals.  It is called EMF of the battery. It's related by standard reduction potentials of its electrodes in chemistry as:
$$ E = E_{cathode} - E_{anode} $$

When the battery is connected to a resistor R, some current I will flow through R, as well as through a small series resistance r, which is the internal resistance of the battery. So effectively, we will get a terminal voltage, V across R, which is lesser than the EMF of the battery. Relations will look like:

$$ V = E - Ir = IR$$

Answer (score 1):

Voltage of a battery cannot be "calculated", it is a given, inherent property of the electrical element. The potential V exists regardless of load or no load.

But if you connect a load R, then the current across the R will be I = V/R.

Comment: Then it all makes more sense. However, how can a voltage level then be predefined if you cannot calculate the voltage?

Comment: The voltage of an element is "predefined" by its internal chemistry, by difference of internal double-layer potentials at different metal electrodes from which a battery is made of.

Answer (score 1):

> If voltage is calculated using the formula V=IR, how can the voltage be calculated of a battery if it is not connected to anything (i.e. no current)?

We don't calculate voltage, we measure it. To do so generally requires that we draw *some* current from the battery but only a tiny amount. Most digital multimeters have an input impedance of about 10 MΩ and hooking this up to a 9 V battery would cause a current draw of \$ \frac {V}{R} = \frac {9}{10M} = 0.9\ µA \$. This is unlikely to cause a problem in most cases.

[image]

*Figure 1. The ICE Supertester 680R analogue multimeter showing the DC and AC loading. The author had one of these for many years.*

The old analog multimeters were typically 20 kΩ/V and the user had to take this into account when making a reading. For example, when on the 10 V DC range the load on the circuit would be 20k * 10 = 200 kΩ and this could load a high impedance circuit significantly.

Answer (score 1):

V=IR is not a universal way to calculate voltage.  It is for the special case where you have a known resistance (R) and a known current thru that resistance (I).  Neither of these apply to *"calculating the voltage of a battery"*, whatever that is supposed to mean.

To a first approximation, you can model a battery as a voltage source in series with a resistance.  Put another way, you model it like a Thevenin source.  To find the value of the voltage source, simply measure the battery with nothing connected.  Since there is no current (the current drawn by the voltmeter is so small that it can be ignored in this application) thru the resistor, the voltage across it is 0.  The battery's open circuit voltage is therefore the voltage of the internal voltage source.

To find the series resistance, apply a modest load on the battery, and measure the external voltage drop.  You assume that the internal voltage source remains the same, and that the drop in external voltage is due to the drop across the resistance.  You find the resistance by Ohm's law: Ω = V / A, where V is the voltage drop across the internal resistance and A the battery current in Amps.